# Show Images with name containing special characters

Tags: java, html, jsp, encoding, upload

I am trying to display some images containing special characters like ☻ ☺ ♥ or Chinese or Arabic characters in their names using jsp...but the images are not getting displayed !!

```
<img src = "pipo².jpg" />
<img src = "pip☺☻♥o².jpg" />
```

What am I doing wrong !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can percent encode the urls using encodeURIComponent in javascript to give you

```
<img src="pip%C3%A2%C2%98%C2%BA%C3%A2%C2%98%C2%BB%C3%A2%C2%99%C2%A5o%C3%82%C2%B2.jpg">
```

Comment: pip².jpg is converted into pip%C2%B2.jpg with encodeURIComponent and its still isn't working :(

Comment: you have pipo².jpg, not pip².jpg in the OP, or is one of those a typo?

Comment: yea..it was a typo
pipo².jpg is converted to pipo%C2%B2.jpg
instead of encodeURIComponent I used escape()..and I image got loaded.
escape() converted pipo².jpg into pipo%B2.jpg
but escape doesn't work with Arabic or Chinese characters :(

Comment: I wrote a small application in .NET..i set the image source to "pipo².jpg" and it got converted into pipo%C2%B2.jpg.. and this seems to work great !! which means there's something wrong with my html page ..trying to find out what exactly is it

Comment: I think I narrowed down the issue..i probably have to configure something in my java application or tomcat..so that it supports characters like

Comment: I had to change the server.xml and add URIEncoding="UTF-8"

Answer (score 3):

Try encoding the filename using [URLEncoder.encode()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) method before the HTML is sent to the page, e.g.

```
String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8").
```

This will convert the characters to entities which can be passed in HTML.

Comment: pip².jpg is converted into pip%C2%B2.jpg
and its still isn't working :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend renaming your files.

Using special characters in src paths is not strictly allowed, you'd have to find the URL style escape codes for those characters.